# Swift_TransportException Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550 5.7.1 Mail contain spam content 204C610003B "

Tags: php, email, smtp, email-spam

## What could be the problem?

I set up mail on my site but now this problem started to occur
could this be blocked for my ip?
so how can i solve the problem?

```
Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport::assertResponseCode
vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:459

    protected function assertResponseCode($response, $wanted)

    {

        if (!$response) {

         [tag:   $this->throwException(new Swift_TransportException('Expected response code '.implode('/', $wanted).' but got an empty response'));

]        }

 

        list($code) = sscanf($response, '%3d');

        $valid = (empty($wanted) || \in_array($code, $wanted));

 

        if ($evt = $this->eventDispatcher->createResponseEvent($this, $response,

            $valid)) {

            $this->eventDispatcher->dispatchEvent($evt, 'responseReceived');

        }

 

        if (!$valid) {

            $this->throwException(new Swift_TransportException('Expected response code '.implode('/', $wanted).' but got code "'.$code.'", with message "'.$response.'"', $code));

        }

    }

 

    /** Get an entire multi-line response using its sequence number */
```

I solved the problem, I'm waiting for your help

Comment: The SMTP service that you're sending messages through is inspecting the content of your messages and rejecting them because they look like spam.

Comment: As well as spam in the content part, it's worth checking whether the from and to addresses involved cause SPF or DMARC violations, i.e. whether you are allowed to use them from the place you're sending from. Both of these can be checked at submission time, so it's common to have these rejected at this point.

Comment: https://flareapp.io/share/oPRqL0Km  - i posted the error here can you help me what the ministers are wrong